# Asp.net flash muti-file uploaders - Is MultiPowUpload ok, or which is the best and easiest?

Tags: asp.net, flash, file-upload

I am considering using the [MultiPowUpload](http://element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx) control from element-it on a project, as well as perhaps on a second.  Does anyone have any feedback on that particular control?  Does it actually work as advertised, handle errors well, etc?

I've played with quite a few others, but that seems the best so far.  The easiest for the junior members to get off and going with, nearly all features out of the box, etc.

Some of what I need to do:

- Multi-select of files (from a single 'browse' click, not multi-textbox)
- Progress bar (client requirement)
- Queue for upload (it's ok if it can only upload immediately)
- Feedback from server - custom error messages (permissions,etc)
- Pass the session ID automatically, but I can use a URL hack for the upload page too
- Be able to remove files from the queue
- Support large files (~50MB, really up to 300mb would be perfect)
- Accessible/usable JS api
- Can change the view style a little bit at least!
- Localizable - *we need english, chinese, italian, and possible a few others*
- *Resume incomplete transfers (eg, connection dropped, so on, **not required**, but ++)*

I've been working with all of these below, and gotten most of them working in demo pages, finding issues as I go along.

- [Fancy Upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/#how-to) - *quite nice, but no feedback from server, uses mootools not jq*
- [MultiPowUpload](http://demo.element-it.com/Examples/multipow/index.htm) - *looks good, resumes, no flash cookie bug, $149*
- **[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)** - *looks reasonable, real world though?*
- **YUI** - *mostly custom code, will work but tedious*
- **[SWFUpload](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/)** - *no progress bar, otherwise pretty basic & good*
- **[JQuery Multifile (fyneworks.com)](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)** - *inconsistent browser support*
- **devex / telerek** - *missing to many required features, sadly*
- [PL UPload](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) - *nice, but missing 'retry' and error reporting.  may be able to add*

So, does anyone have any real-world experience with MultiPowUpload, or have suggestions for a free or commercial option?

**PL UPLOAD WON** - for now!  If we get complaints, or find it doesn't work in our real life scenarios, then we'll consider switching to MultiPowUpload.  But it is good enough, and we can write some JS to do a few of the missing things.  With chunking I had no problems with 300mb uploads.  Yay.

Comment: hmmm, i tried `Telerik` control ,and i find it so nice and customizable , Why u said not good enough?!.
And as for `MultiPowUpload`,the first time i hear about it , and hopefully u told us about it, but Does it allow u to save the path of the file in your database?!

Comment: @just_name, I don't mean the quality is bad, sorry.  It just misses too many of the requirements for this project.  Normally I would buy devex, but theirs misses them too.  I'm not sure what  you mean by the database question.  It posts to a page on the server, so at that point you can save things anywhere.  I'm sure it won't post directly to a DB though.

Comment: Going with PL Upload for now, and designing the process around the limitations.  If we need something better (with proper pause/resume) then we'll spend more time and buy the other one.  It's a godo chance for the guys to start using jquery anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did U try this one.

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

> Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash,
>   BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as
>   upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

Comment: Saw a screenshot of it somewhere, but didn't know what it was.  Looking at it now.

Comment: Right now I don't see a way to 'retry' or 'remove' a failed item.  It is way too common that all these uploaders only handle the 'success' case, and when it comes to errors (io/reporting/etc) they fall down.  I'm sure I can add it, somehow, though.  But I shouldn't have to, this is a standard requirement.  Can you imaging if gmail let you attach, but never "removed" the failed uploads from your list?  Sigh.  90% of the way, again.

Comment: Just missing retry, and a few other small things.  Pretty much what we need, so we may go with it and if the users don't have issues often, keep it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man, if you hadn't mentioned it I might have had to deal with purchasing dept :)